# Событие на нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии, например, кнопки "А" выходило сообщение. Что-то типа:

```
var x = 9;    
Нажатие кнопки "А" (или любой другой) : {
        alert (x)
};
```

Comment: **Я не разбираюсь в программировании** и не надо начинать, за вас всегда сделают **вашу работу**, добрые люди из интернета =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = 9;
// обработчик нажатия на кнопку
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  // если кнопка - "a" латинская маленькая
  if (e.key === 'a') {
    alert(x);
  }
});
```

Comment: лучше использовать `event.code`, так как сейчас у вас регистрозависимое значение используется, если нажат `capslock` ничего не будет показано

Comment: @ThisMan так и задумано, что бы работало только на маленькую :)

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="showX()">Show X</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showX() {
    alert(x)
};
```

Comment: где тут кнопка "А"?

Comment: <button onclick="showX()" id="A">A</button>
или тебе ещё атрибутов накидать?

Comment: можно накидать, только вопрос, похоже, был про кнопку **на клавиатуре**, а не то что у вас)

Comment: разницу клавиши и кнопки рассказать?

Comment: расскажите, я послушаю)

Comment: _"Кнопка - понятие абстрактное, а клавиша - физическое. Кнопка на экране (форме) , а клавиша - на клавиатуре"_ 
Ответ из гугла

Comment: @Данил огорчу вас, но вики с вам не согласна https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кнопка_(техника)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков огорчу вас, но вики не является 100% достоверным источником т.к. это редактируемая библиотека

Comment: @Данил а какой ресурс НЕ является редактируемым в интернете? :-) А вообще, из контекста вопроса больше похоже на клавишу на клавиатуре. Но, конечно, можно прочитать и так итак. Поставил вам плюс, а ТС минус.